# Git Clone is too slow

Tags: tortoisegit, git-clone, git-bash, git

This is my first time to construct the git server. When I use TortoiseGit-1.8.1.0-32bit to handle the operation, everything is fine!

But if i use the `git clone` command or git bash, the git clone process speed is so slow. I've attached two images showing the relative `git clone` transfer speeds below.

Can anybody give me some suggestions?

[image: Cloning via TortoiseGit]

[image: Cloning via git command]

Comment: Define "slow" please. Showing the output of the command would help us diagnose the problem as well.

Comment: @RyanBigg see the links

Comment: Is Tortoise configured any differently?

Comment: Does http://superuser.com/questions/485638/tortoisegit-really-slow-on-windows-7-machine help? (one of the answers at least)

Comment: When i use TortoiseGit, the speed is normal. Only use git command or git bash,  the speed is slow down.

Comment: the only thing "worked for me".. disconnecting and connecting pc to wifi... in my office..

Answer (score 43):

Maybe you can fetch only the latest revision first and then fetch the rest:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:joe/hello-world.git
$ cd hello-world
$ git fetch --unshallow
```

Thanks [this article](https://codeyarns.com/2016/01/12/slow-speed-on-git-clone/)!

Comment: Is this due to the amount of commits in a project, so metadata of it grows, and get slow?

Answer (score 5):

If you, like me, have configured TortoiseGit to use Putty's plink to connect (and use pageant, etc...), this might help you:

Try enabling in Putty (Default Settings) the following settings:

1. **SSH -> Auth: "Allow agent forwarding"** (I believe this is the one that changes "everything")
2. SSH -> "Enable Compression"
3. Session -> Select "Default Settings" -> **Save**

For me, this resulted in going from 143.00 KiB/s to **4.50 MiB/s**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues at play here:

1. Your OpenSSL is not up to date
2. The SSH protocol is slower than HTTPS (but not by much)

**Part 1. OpenSSL**

After following the directions from the article, http://darrell.mozingo.net/2011/09/29/painfully-slow-clone-speeds-with-msysgit-gitextensions/, I successfully boosted my network throughput for the `git clone` operation from 1 MiB/s to 28 MiB/s.  This result was achieved by upgrading OpenSSL from version 0.9.8e to version 1.0.1e.

**Part 2. SSH protocol**

The SSH protocol a little bit slower than the HTTPS protocol, but not enough to warrant the speed differences I mentioned in Part 1 or what you are seeing.  Please read through this article for more information on the Git protocols: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tsgit/chap-008-extract.html.

Comment: Hey, you said you're using OpenSSL 1.0.1e. This is a vulnerable version to the Heartbleed expolit. I recommend upgrading to 1.0.1g or later as soon as possible.

Comment: OpenSSH (the client) doesn't use OpenSSL in a way that makes him vulnerable to Heartbleed, I don't think.

Comment: Your typical msysgit comes with OpenSSL 4, from 2007, which has the bug. You can use [version 6 (Jun 2015) of OpenSSL, built by mls-soft](http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html) to save the day.